# Plotly: How to automate y-axis with space for texttemplate?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

i try to figure out how to plot this barchart with texttemplate. without cutting them, but also keep the y-axis dynamic. thanks for ideas!

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
df.lifeExp = df.lifeExp/100
fig = px.bar(df, y='lifeExp', x='country', text='lifeExp')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=20, uniformtext_mode='show')
plotly.io.write_image(fig, file='bartest.png', format='png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `uniformtext_minsize=20` will make your figure look crowded either way. So instead of `fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='outside')` I would actually go for:

```
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='inside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=12, uniformtext_mode='show')
```

#### Plot 1

[image]

Plotly adjusts the size of the yaxis to the size of the bars and not the texts added to it afterwards, so this way you'll prevent any problems with cutting off text. If you for some reason prefer to keep the text elements above the bars, you'll have to adjust the y-aixs accordingly with, for example:

```
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, max(df.lifeExp)*1.2])
```

But as you can see you'll have to set `uniformtext_minsize` to an impractically low number in order to make the text elements readable:

#### Plot 2

[image]

#### Complete code for Plot 1

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
df.lifeExp = df.lifeExp/100
fig = px.bar(df, y='lifeExp', x='country', text='lifeExp')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='inside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=11, uniformtext_mode='show')
# plotly.io.write_image(fig, file='bartest.png', format='png')


fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for Plot 2

import plotly.express as px

```
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
df.lifeExp = df.lifeExp/100
fig = px.bar(df, y='lifeExp', x='country', text='lifeExp')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=5, uniformtext_mode='show')
# plotly.io.write_image(fig, file='bartest.png', format='png')
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, max(df.lifeExp)*1.2])

fig.show()
```

Comment: vestland... the person how solves all the ploty-problems- thank you